# how to include "enter key" in python

Tags: python, key, enter

```
import subprocess

path = '/home/test/net.keystore'

text = subprocess.Popen(['keytool', '-list', '-v', '-keystore', path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file = text.stdout.read().decode().splitlines()
print file
```

> through subprocess i trying to fetch keystore certificate details I
> don't know password for keystore. If i press "enter key" twice then
> output is processing
>
> Is there any way to automate "Enter key" in python?

Comment: how about attaching you code...

Comment: Not asking for the enter key twice in code?

Comment: turn it off then on  again?

Comment: Apologies miss the code

Answer (score 8):

You can use `keyboard` module which you can install using `pip` with command `python -m pip install keyboard`.

**Following code will press the enter key:**

```
from keyboard import press
press('enter')
```

Answer (score 1):

This installation process worked for me:
`C:\Python3>pip.exe install keyboard`

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
```

I used Win10, a simple press(`'enter'`) that just deactivated the active button, but press and release worked.
[python3](/questions/tagged/python3)[python](/questions/tagged/python)[presskey](/questions/tagged/presskey)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted a solution for os, not web.